# UITextField show cursor even when userInteractionEnabled is set to NO

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextfield

I have a UITextField and it must blink the cursor anyway, even its userInteractionEnabled property is set to NO. I don't want the UITextField to becomeFirstResponder and show the keyboard.

Now you may be asking:

**1. If you want to hide the keyboard, why to show the cursor?**

A: The problem is that I need to show the user the UITextField is being edited, with a different/custom keyboard.

**2. So why don't you use the inputView property?**

A: Because the keyboard in inputView comes up from bottom, and I want my custom keyboard in the center of the screen.

So let's go to the real question:

**How can I show the cursor? Is there any property I can set? If not, how I would draw a cursor? Making a UIView that gets added and removed with alpha, or subclassing UITextField and overriding drawInRect?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a small UIView with a repeting animation that sets the alpha to 0 and 1 back and forth with `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 
                      delay:0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat 
                 animations:^{ [cursorView setAlpha:0]; }
                 completion:^(BOOL animated){ [cursorView setAlpha:1]; } ];
```

To position the view correctly as a subview of the textfield, in front of the text entered, you can use the `NSString` method `sizewithfont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:`

Comment: Wow, didn't know about `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat`. I'll try that!

Comment: @andreamazz Can you please explain this point "To position the view correctly as a subview of the textfield, in front of the text entered, you can use the NSString method sizewithfont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:" I mean how to use this method? Can you please write an example usage?

Comment: @AnthonSanthez this is an 8 years old answer, that method is now deprecated, you can however chack the documentation for its substitute: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1531844-sizewithattributes

Comment: @andreamazz thank you, I've read the documentation you provided but I couldn't find a sample implementation. Can you show a small example implementation of blinking cursor if not difficult for you?