# Always Display Cursor UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to create a UITextField that will always display the blinking cursor whether the keyboard is displaying or not.

Is there any way I can achieve this effect?

Comment: Why do you want this? It may help in getting appropriate answers.

Comment: I just want a user to know he can edit a text field that I have changed the look of. Im not sure if its a good idea but I just wanted to learn how to do this

Comment: `UITextField` will only show the cursor when it is the first responder and the keyboard is shown. You will have to make your own cursor and show that at other times.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128509/uitextfield-show-cursor-even-when-userinteractionenabled-is-set-to-no

Comment: Thanks rmaddy but I'm pretty new to swift and cannot translate that objective-c code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@andreamazz answer in Swift.

[UITextField show cursor even when userInteractionEnabled is set to NO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128509/uitextfield-show-cursor-even-when-userinteractionenabled-is-set-to-no)

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0, options: .Repeat, animations: {() -> Void in
cursorView.alpha = 0 }, completion: {(animated: Bool) -> Void in
cursorView.alpha = 1
})
```

Comment: Hey how would I use this with a textField? Also I get unresolved identifier cursorView should I define it first?

Comment: Yes, the cursorView is a small UIView which would replace the cursor in UITextField. You will have to place this at the end of the textView and make it set the alpha from 0 to 1 on repeat. (the function I gave you)

Comment: Alright I think i get the gist. Let me know if you come up with code sample that actually works because it seems like this would take me a while to figure out. I'll still accept your answer if noone provides a better one