# How to make visible Cursor on TextField when keyboard not visible in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

The text field cursor is only visible after calling `textField.becomeFirstResponder()` and is invisible after `textField.resignFirstResponder()`. But I want to make visible the cursor after `textFieldDidEndEditing` or before `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`.

Then what can I do?

Comment: Customize it.
I think [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128509/uitextfield-show-cursor-even-when-userinteractionenabled-is-set-to-no) will help you some.

Comment: Customize it.
I think [The answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128509/uitextfield-show-cursor-even-when-userinteractionenabled-is-set-to-no) will help some.

Comment: Actually you shouldn't. You are changing the expected behavior of the UI.

Comment: Thanks @dengApro. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think UITextField can display a cursor while it isn't the first responder. Maybe you can try making a custom UITextField subclass?

Comment: Can you please give a simple example or can share any resource?